# Datasets in Bar graph is plotting wrong in MpAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for drawing Barchart .I have following datasets:

```
DataSet, label: LABEL 0, entries: 21

[Entry, x: 1.0 y: 21.0],[Entry, x: 2.0 y: 10.0],
[Entry, x: 3.0 y: 19.0],[Entry, x: 4.0 y: 10.0],
[Entry, x: 5.0 y: 11.0],[Entry, x: 6.0 y: 14.0],
[Entry, x: 7.0 y: 11.0],[Entry, x: 8.0 y: 16.0],
[Entry, x: 9.0 y: 16.0],[Entry, x: 10.0 y: 8.0],
[Entry, x: 11.0 y: 10.0],[Entry, x: 12.0 y: 16.0],
[Entry, x: 13.0 y: 16.0],[Entry, x: 14.0 y: 12.0],
[Entry, x: 15.0 y: 17.0],[Entry, x: 16.0 y: 15.0],
[Entry, x: 17.0 y: 7.0],[Entry, x: 18.0 y: 17.0],
[Entry, x: 19.0 y: 10.0],[Entry, x: 20.0 y: 9.0],[Entry, x: 21.0 y: 10.0]

DataSet, label: LABEL 1, entries: 5
[Entry, x: 1.0 y: 1.0],
[Entry, x: 2.0 y: 1.0],
[Entry, x: 3.0 y: 1.0],
[Entry, x: 8.0 y: 4.0], 
[Entry, x: 11.0 y: 1.0] 

DataSet, label: LABEL 2, entries: 21
[Entry, x: 1.0 y: 57.0],[Entry, x: 2.0 y: 88.0],
[Entry, x: 3.0 y: 72.0],[Entry, x: 4.0 y: 82.0],
[Entry, x: 5.0 y: 84.0],[Entry, x: 6.0 y: 74.0],
[Entry, x: 7.0 y: 72.0],[Entry, x: 8.0 y: 82.0],
[Entry, x: 9.0 y: 66.0],[Entry, x: 10.0 y: 57.0],
[Entry, x: 11.0 y: 51.0],[Entry, x: 12.0 y: 44.0],
[Entry, x: 13.0 y: 52.0],[Entry, x: 14.0 y: 52.0],
[Entry, x: 15.0 y: 58.0],[Entry, x: 16.0 y: 53.0],
[Entry, x: 17.0 y: 54.0],[Entry, x: 18.0 y: 47.0],
[Entry, x: 19.0 y: 58.0],[Entry, x: 20.0 y: 60.0],[Entry, x: 21.0 y: 2.0]
```

The following is the image of the bar graph which is plotted incorrectly

[image]

In the above graph the values are plotted incorrectly . Please look at the dataset 2 which has 5 entries wherein x values [4,5,6,7] are not there but in the graph it has plotted continuously, also I've 21 entries in set1 and set3 there's a mismatch when this data is plotted only 15 records is plotted for set 1 and 14 records is plotted for set 3.

I have tried number of ways, can someone tell me if this kind of dataset can be drawn.